# TypeError: s.text(...).addClass is not a function

Tags: oracle-apex

need help or tip about an extrange error that appear on my apex aplication when i try to populate a list of values.

here is my query:

```
select 
replace(customer_id,'30000-','') || ': ' || FIRST_NAME || ', ' || STREET_ADDRESS1 || ', ' || STREET_ADDRESS2 || ', ' ||  PHONE_NUMBER1 || ', ' ||  LAST_NAME  || ', ' ||PHONE_NUMBER2 || ', [' || VISIT_DAY || ']' a, customer_id b
from sib_customers
where salesman = :APP_USER
and visit_day = :P1_VISIT_DAY
order by FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
```

i got aroud 30 users (:APP_USER) that connects to the app. each user has his own customers list, the app executes the query and populates all customers for each one in the correct way, excep for one called : SALESMAN9 and i choose values for visit day like: 'DAY 2' or 'DAY 10' i got the next error:

```
TypeError: s.text(...).addClass is not a function
...ollapsiblebound",!0).bind("expand collapse",function(t){var n=t.type==="collapse...
```

if i execute my query in the database with any of this values, it worked very well, so i just don't know what could be the problem...any tips .....

thanks,
mj

Comment: This is a javascript error you're getting, not an error during render?

Comment: Perhaps this JavaScript error is due to a template that your using.

Comment: Hi tom. the error appears when i run the page.

Comment: Hi  Rohan, but why it only happen with this one user ?, the rest 29 users work perfect..thanks

Comment: Hi Siberia. Apex version? Where you execute this query (report, interactive report, tree, LOV query of select-list...)? Have you any extra javascript code at your page? Any plugins?

Answer (score 0):

> s.text(...).addClass is not a function

This is a JQuery error. Whatever `s.text(...)` returns, it is not a JQuery object. It looks like there is an error in your function call `s.text(...)`.